# Create ext4 image skipping free space

Tags: backup, ext4, imaging

To backup an ext4 partition the easy way is just to use `cat` or `dd`:

```
cat /dev/sdXn > backup.img
dd if=/dev/sdXn of=backup.img
```

This of course is just a low level copy, so also the unused disk space will be backed up to the image (and unless the unused space is zeroed before creating the image, it will waste space also if the image is compressed).

Is there an easy way to do a more smart ext4 backup (at file system level, so not just a `tar` of the content of the folders and files), skipping the unused space, without resorting to tools like clonezilla?

Answer (score 1):

You can use e2image -r which will create a sparse file of only the metadata and data blocks which are in use.    This can then be compressed, but when you uncompress the compressed raw image, you may then get much larger file because it is not sparse.    To get around this problem, you can use e2image -Q which will create a qcow2 file.

Comment: Are you sure that the -r option will also save the data blocks? The man for e2image says that indirect blocks and directory blocks will be included, but "this will only send the metadata information, without any data blocks".

Comment: Also from the man file: "Normally e2image only includes fs metadata, not regular file data.  The -a option can be specified to include all data."